# Prove that $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $g(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z}}f(z)$ when $f(z)$ is analytic on $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series, singularity

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function on $z=0$ and let $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z}}f(z)$. Given $f(z)\not\equiv0$, prove that $z=0$ is an essential singularity of $g(z)$.

---

The only way I know to prove a point $z_0$ is an essential singularity of a function $g(z)$, is to prove that the Laurent Series of the function $g(z)$ around the point $z_0$ has an infinite amount of negative order powers. So this is what I tried to do.

First, if $f(z)\not\equiv0$, then $z=0$ is a zero of a finite order of $f(z)$; meaning there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(z)=z^mh(z)$, when $h(z)$ is analytic on $z=0$ and $h(z)\neq0$. Then:

$$g(z)=e^\frac{1}{z}z^mh(z)$$

If $h(z)$ is analytic on $z=0$, then it has a Taylor Series around it: $h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h_nz^n$ when actually $h_n=\frac{h^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. To conclude:

$$g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!z^k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}h_nz^{n+m}$$

This unfortunately doesn't promise that the actual Laurent Series of $g(z)$ would have an infinite amount of negative order powers (since they can cancel each other, allegedly).

Comment: $e^\frac{1}{z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!z^k}$ and $f(z)=f(0)+o(1)$. The result is immediate.

Comment: @Surb what does $o(1)$ mean? And what if $f(0)=0$? Could you please be more informative?

Comment: You could show that it can't have finite order. If it had, there'd be an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}}f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$. Show this is unbounded near $0$ and conclude.

Comment: Why does $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z=0$? The question says it's never zero.

Comment: @goodatthis The question says that $f$ is not equivalent to the zero function. This means that the zeroes of $f$ are isolated.

Comment: Okay, didn’t notice the subtle notation. I guess a better question to ask is why do you know f has a zero AT z = 0?